# Is there a way to intercept items before they are added to the DOM in an HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, rendering

I don't think what I want is possible but I thought I would ask anyway!

Is there a way to grab stuff in the initial HTML file, modify it and then add it to the DOM **before** it has rendered?

For example I have an HTML file:

```
<body>
    <div>Something here</div>
</body>
```

Is there a way I can intercept that `<div>` before it is added to the DOM as the HTML file is parsed.

I do not want to modify it **after** it has already been added to the page for clarity.

For another example, if I have an `<img src="someimage.jpg">` is there a way to change that `src` attribute before the image gets added to the DOM so the request is never made.

Happy enough to use inline JS in the `<head>` (well I assume that is what I would have to do anyway if this is actually possible.)

**I know once I have a service worker this all becomes arbitrary but I am working on the assumption of a cold cache and no external files (it is to optimise "above the fold" content primarily).**

Comment: Did you consider using MutationObserver ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: Yes but I am unsure how I could use that to change something **before** it is added to the DOM, does it not detail what has already happened?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to watch for HTML changes before they are applied. The best solution would be to use a Mutation observer and edit the src attribute once the img has been added

Comment: Yeah I thought that might be my answer, but at that point the request for the image will already be made surely? At that point it would make things worse as I would double up requests? I know once I have a service worker this all becomes arbitrary but I am working on the assumption of a cold cache and no external files (it is to optimise "above the fold" content primarily).

Comment: Not exactly sure what your situation is (do you have access to backend, Why is the action required, etc.?), but maybe an "empty" initial page and javascript that requests your new page, preprocessed the content string and then replaces the placeholder webpage? Somewhat similar to the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

A cheap and simple way to prevent HTML from rendering is to wrap it in a `<template>`.

Templates will be parsed during page load like any normal HTML, but put in different `documentFragment`s instead of being rendered, waiting to be manipulated, cloned or inserted anywhere you want when you are ready to render.

HTTP requests will not fire.

```html
<template id="some_tpl">
  <img src="someimage.jpg">
</template>
```

```js
const template = document.getElementById('some_tpl');
const templateContent = template.content;
document.body.appendChild(templateContent);
```